# Query Account team and concatenate results

Tags: apex, query, loop

My requirement is to create a new record that has data from Opportunity, Account, Product, OLI Account Team, and Opportunity Team. I have the code written so that in a for loop I query for the OLI records and then use that to create a Revenue Pipeline record.

I'm unsure how to get all the Account team members and where. Do I add as another action in the for loop? and once I get a list of the team members how can I concatenate them into a string together, do you have to count the number of records returned and then use that to space the results out? If my query returns:

Tom
Dick 
Harry

I can get to 'Tom, Dick, Harry' so I can populate a text field.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
public with sharing class RevenuePipelineHandler {
public static void createRevPipeline(Set<Id> oppyIds) {
    List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> revPipeline = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
    String revType;

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli:[SELECT Id,
                                        Start_Date__c, 
                                        End_Date__c,
                                        TotalPrice,
                                        Is_Fund__c,
                                        OpportunityId,
                                        Opportunity.AccountId,
                                        Opportunity.Account.Account_BU_2__c,
                                        Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode,
                                        Opportunity.Practice__c,
                                        Opportunity.Cash_or_Barter__c,
                                        Opportunity.StageName,
                                        Opportunity.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c,
                                        Product2Id,
                                        Product2.ALR_Retailer__c,
                                        Product2.Product_LOB__c,
                                        Product2.Product_Type__c,
                                        Product2.Family,
                                        Product2.Product_Group__c,
                                        Product2.Product_Offering__c
                                        FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppyIds])
    {
        if(
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Prospecting/Business Issue Identified' ||
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Scoping/Building Business Case' ||
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Proposal Development' ||
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Price & Product Negotiation' ||
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Contracting'){
                revType = 'Pipeline';
                }
        if(
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Renew'){
                revType = 'Renewal';
                }
        if(
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed - Won' &&
            oli.Opportunity.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c == null){
                revType = 'Closed - Won Not Reconciled';
                }
        if(
            oli.Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed - Won' &&
            oli.Opportunity.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c != null){
                revType = 'Booked';
                }
        else{
            revType = 'Unknown';
        }
        List<Product_Structure__c> externalId = [SELECT Id 
                                                 FROM Product_Structure__c 
                                                 WHERE External_Id__c = :oli.Product2.Family + '/' + oli.Product2.Product_Group__c + '/' + oli.Product2.Product_Offering__c];
        String accountTeam = 
        revPipeline.add(new Revenue_Pipeline__c(
            Account__c = oli.Opportunity.AccountId,
            ALR_Retailer__c = oli.Product2.ALR_Retailer__c,
            Cash_Barter__c = oli.Opportunity.Cash_or_Barter__c,
            Cross_Practice__c = oli.Opportunity.Account.Account_BU_2__c,
            CurrencyIsoCode = oli.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode,
            External_Id__c = oli.Product2.Family + '/' + oli.Product2.Product_Group__c + '/' + oli.Product2.Product_Offering__c,
            Is_Fund__c = oli.Is_Fund__c,
            Name = oli.OpportunityId + '-' + oli.Id,
            Opportunity__c = oli.OpportunityId,
            Opportunity_OLI__c = oli.OpportunityId + '-' + oli.Id,
            Practice__c = oli.Opportunity.Practice__c,
            Product_AU__c = oli.Product2.Product_LOB__c,
            Product_End_Date__c = oli.End_Date__c,
            Product_Price__c = oli.TotalPrice,
            Product_Start_Date__c = oli.Start_Date__c,
            Product_Structure__c = externalId[0].Id,
            Product__c = oli.Product2Id,
            Revenue_Type__c = revType,
            Subscription_Type__c = oli.Product2.Product_Type__c));
        }
    try{
        upsert revPipeline Opportunity_OLI__c;              
    } catch (DmlException ex) {
        System.debug('The folloing Exception has occured: ' + ex.getMessage() + ' at line ' + ex.getLineNumber());
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at dlrs? There's an `Aggregate Operation` called `Concatenate Distinct`.

Comment: I have, because this custom object and the Account Team object are not related do you think the best way is dlrs on Account populated text field, and then bring that text field into my query?

Comment: Exactly thus. Get the concatenated team member names on the `Account` first, then move from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation here is to use [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to create a rollup of `AccountTeamMember` to `Account` using the `Aggregate Operation` of `Concatenate Distinct` and a `Field to Aggregate` of `User.Name` or `User.FirstName`. You can specify a `Concatenate Delimiter` of `,SP()`. The library uses `SP()` to add a space in the `Concatenate Delimiter`.

Now you'll have a field on `Account` called something like `Team_Member_Names__c`, which you can pull into other objects via formula (on `Opportunity` or even `OpportunityLineItem`).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to have the delimiter accept spaces? When you do `, ` it ignores the space and just squishes them together. if you do something like `', '` then it adds the apostrophe as well..

Comment: No, I haven't tried to include whitespace in the delimiter. I imagine the code calls `trim` on it, removing outer whitespace. Hmm...

Comment: Apparently this is already a feature, I'm just on the wrong version.. https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues/278